# How to receive e-mail notification on CPM completion using IBM Rational UCM Clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I want to receive an e-mail notification on completion of every CPM. I am using IBM rational Clearcase(UCM).Please let me know if there is any script to do this?

Thanks
Sooraj

Answer (score 0):

What is CPM? The [Core Protection Module of Tivoli](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/wikis/home/wiki/Tivoli%20Endpoint%20Manager/page/CPM%20Automatic%20Updates?lang=en)?

Anyway, you can setup post-operation trigger for email notification, as commented in the [Ten Best Script page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/4311.html#N101CA).

A complete example can be seen in ClearCase Help pages "[E-mail notification postoperation trigger script](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_pstop_scrpt.htm)".
It setup includes, for an UCM deliver operation:

> creates a postoperation trigger type that fires when a developer finishes a deliver operation, as represented by the `deliver_complete` opkind.
>   The `mktrtype` command uses the `-stream` option to indicate that the trigger type applies only to deliver operations that target the specified integration stream.

```
# This is a Perl script to set up the triggertype
# for e-mail notification on deliver.
use Config;

# define platform-dependent arguments.
my $PVOBTAG;
if   ($Config{'osname'} eq 'MSWin32') {
   $PVOBTAG  = '\cyclone_pvob';
   $WCMD     = '-execwin "ccperl \\\\pluto\disk1\ucmtrig_examples\ex2\ex2_postop.pl"';
}
else {
   $PVOBTAG  = '/pvobs/cyclone_pvob';
   $WCMD     = '-execwin "ccperl \\\\\\pluto\disk1\ucmtrig_examples\ex2\ex2_postop.pl"';
}
my $STREAM = "stream:P1_int\@$PVOBTAG";
my $TRTYPE = "trtype:ex2_postop\@$PVOBTAG";
my $UCMD   = '-execunix "Perl /net/pluto/disk1/ucmtrig_examples/ex2/ex2_postop.pl"';

print 'cleartool mktrtype -ucmobject -all -postop deliver_complete $WCMD $UCMD -stream $STREAM -nc $TRTYPE';
```

The key part is:

```
cleartool mktrtype -ucmobject -all -postop deliver_complete
```